# Unable to out the file when i click on download in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi all i am having a `grid view` in which i use `AJAX update panel` . I will bind the items from `Database` to grid view so that when user clicks on `Download` which is available i would like to `download` the file and prompt the user for save or cancel. I write all the relevant code when i am running it with out update panel i am able to prompt the file but the same code with update panel didn't give me the output i required..

My design

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAll" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" runat="server" />
 </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="ID" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' runat="server" />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="deleteRec" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName">
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="LblFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("File_Name") %>'>        </asp:Label>
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="LblFileName1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("File_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="img" runat="Server" CommandName="Image" ImageUrl="~/images/view1.png" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DownLoad" SortExpression="FileName">
  <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDow" runat="server" CommandName="DOWNLOAD">Download</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEdit" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;
               height: auto; width: auto;">
    <br />
  <table align="center">
  <tr>
  <td>
   <asp:GridView ID="dynamicGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
   <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  </asp:GridView>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="center">
  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClientClick="return Hidepopup()" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
   </asp:Panel>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false" PopupControlID="pnlAddEdit" TargetControlID="lnkFake" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
 </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my code in `Row command` event

```
 if (e.CommandName == "DOWNLOAD")
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString");
        string FileName = string.Empty;
        FileName = "venkat.txt";
        string strPath1 = Server.MapPath("AchTemplates") + "\\" + "venkat.txt";

        int id1 = 0;

        //string strLine = string.Empty;
        // string[] lines = null;

        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
        cnn.Open();
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
        //Label l = (Label)grdACH.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Label1");
        //Label l = (Label)grdACH.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblid");
        //strid = ((Label)grdACH.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblid")).Text.ToString();
        //id = Convert.ToInt16(l.Text);
        string strid = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1")).Text.ToString();
        id1 = Convert.ToInt16(strid);
        string selectSQL = "Select File_Data from tblachmaster where ID IN (" + id1 + ")";

        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(selectSQL, cnn);
        // cmd1.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        //DataTable dt1 = GetData1(cmd1);
        DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        // oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_FedTaxID", FedTaxID);
        oAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd2;

        oAdapter.Fill(oDataSet);

        DataTable dt1 = oDataSet.Tables[0];
        //string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(strPath);
        if (dt1 != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt1.Rows[i]["File_Data"];
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                //lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n");

                // sb.Append(lines.ToString());

                sb.Append(text.ToString());

                // strLine = convertArrayToString(lines);
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(strPath1, sb.ToString());
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=genACH(CCD).txt");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.Output.Write(strPath1);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
```

But i am unable to fire the one i required can any one help me

Comment: You won't be able to use the UpdatePanel in conjunction with a download request, if you download the file by posting back to the server.  The UpdatePanel will mess that up...

Comment: Then how can i achieve this as per my requirement

Comment: Remove the UpdatePanel, or add triggers to respond only to certain events

Comment: Then i will miss out the pop up which i am showing

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have the link button perform a normal postback. One approach is to change the `linkbutton` in your item template to something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href='FileDownloader.aspx?Id='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>Download</a>
```

And then create a Page called FileDownloader.aspx with something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString");
        string FileName = string.Empty;
        FileName = "venkat.txt";
        string strPath1 = Server.MapPath("AchTemplates") + "\\" + "venkat.txt";

        int id1 = 0;

        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
        cnn.Open();
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;


        id1 = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        string selectSQL = "Select File_Data from tblachmaster where ID IN (" + id1 + ")";

        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(selectSQL, cnn);
        DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter oAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        oAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd2;

        oAdapter.Fill(oDataSet);

        DataTable dt1 = oDataSet.Tables[0];
        if (dt1 != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt1.Rows[i]["File_Data"];
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                sb.Append(text.ToString());

            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(strPath1, sb.ToString());
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=genACH(CCD).txt");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.Output.Write(strPath1);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

}
```

**NOTE**: Above code is completely untested. I took your code and pasted it removing your comments only and making one little adjustment to get the Id.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button as a `PostBackTrigger` in the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DownloadButton" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- GridView -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put following code inside GridviewRowDatabound..

```
ScriptManager scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
LinkButton linkDow= e.Row.FindControl("linkDow") as LinkButton;
if (btn != null)
{
scriptMan.RegisterPostBackControl(linkDow);
}
```

For More Details [Click here](http://aspdotnet41.blogspot.in/2014/04/unable-to-download-xls-file-on-click.html)